# how to install apache latest stable 2.4.16 in ubuntu server?

Tags: apache2

i use **apt-get install apache2** after installation apache version is 2.4.6. But i want the latest 2.4.16 version. I also tried it to install from source using **WGET** after downloading packages from source i used make install command but it shows error.

Comment: You'll  need to give more information about what error you see, if you want someone to help